# Updating columns in PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, sql-update

// Updating a column using **PDO** extenstion in PHP //

I guess the title says it all, but when I tried to update a column, the first statement or the first query actually works, but when I tried to update another column from another table, it is not now working.

Here is my query with the execution of it:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `verify` SET status=100 WHERE username=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($username));

if($stmt){
  $adminsql = "UPDATE `admin_info` SET status=100 WHERE username=?";
  $adminstmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $adminstmt->execute(array($username));

  if($adminstmt){
    echo 'Success!';
  }
}
```

The verify column is updated but the admin_info is not being updated since that they also have the same query.

**EDIT:**
I've changed the `$result['username']` to `$username`, because it requires more code to be displayed here, and I want this to be simplified or minified, or just show a snippet of my code.

Comment: Where is `$result` set?

Comment: Please see the edit, thank you

Comment: You call `$sql` query twice. In Admin execution you should have `$adminsql`